# How to write to a file under sysfs from Kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I want to start [RAID integrity check](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Scrubbing_the_drives) from pod. For that, I need to write some data in /sys/block/mdX/md/sync_action file. I don't want to use privileged container. So, far I have tried below things.

1. Set access control for user and set below securityContext

   ```
       securityContext:
         runAsUser: some-user-id
         runAsGroup: some-user-gid
   ```

   But, setfacl is not working for this file(same command works for other files in my system)

   ```
   [root@hpe ~]# setfacl -m 'u:some-user:rw' /sys/class/block/md0/md/sync_action
   setfacl: /sys/class/block/md0/md/sync_action: Invalid argument
   ```
2. Change ownership of the file and run pod with above mentioned securityContext

   ```
   [root@hpe]# ls -l /sys/class/block/md0/md/sync_action
   -rw-r--r-- 1 some-user root 4096 Jul 26 12:16 /sys/class/block/md0/md/sync_action
   ```

   But, this is also not working

   ```
   [root@hpe ~]# kubectl exec -it centos -- bash
   bash-4.2$ ls -l /sys/class/block/md0/md/sync_action
   -rw-r--r-- 1 997 root 4096 Jul 27 03:28 /sys/class/block/md0/md/sync_action
   bash-4.2$ echo "check" > /sys/class/block/md0/md/sync_action
   bash: /sys/class/block/md0/md/sync_action: Read-only file system
   ```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a workload that would typically run in Kubernetes; usually containerized processes don't have direct access to the host hardware devices.  (If you can directly access the host hard disk then you can bypass pretty much all other constraints on what your process could do.)  Does it make more sense to run this directly on the host system, not in a container?

Answer (score 0):

i have seen `/sys` went read-only when the container is using host networking.

While sometimes `kube-proxy` container in `kube-system` also running in privileges mode.

you can try running your **POD** or **container** in priveledges mode.

For **pod**, you can update the

```
 securityContext:
  privileged: true
```

Also, you can try changing the user in the docker container if **kubectl** **exec** won't allow go over to the **Node** and try to access the container directly and try with the root user once for debugging.

Are you using **Jessie** or **alpine** as the base image in container ?